# Is there a geometric interpretation for this quantity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

**Edit:**  According to the  comment of Prof. Bryant, I revise my  question.

Is there a  reasonable  and  non trivial  (geometric) interpretation for the  following quantity on a  compact  Riemannian  manifold $(M,g)$ of  dimension $3$

$$q=\sup_{\alpha}\int_M \alpha \wedge d\alpha $$

where $\sup$ is taken over all $1$-forms $\alpha$ of $g$-length $1$.

Comment: First, the Euler characteristic of any compact $3$-manifold without boundary is $0$, so this is no restriction.  Second, if $\alpha(Y) = g(X,Y)$ for *all* vector fields $Y$, then $\alpha = X^\flat$, so there is only one such $\alpha$ for any given unit vector field $X$.  Can you reformulate your question?  Did you want to just require that $\alpha(X)=1$, which still allows for some variation in $\alpha$?  Now the metric is irrelevant.  It only depends on $X$.

Comment: I am  sorry  for  not  paying  attention to  the  Euler  characteristic  of  odd  dimensional  manifold.  Moreover, to  every  unit  length vector  field $X$ we  associate a  i-form $\alpha_X$  with $\alpha_X(Y)=<X,Y>$. Then  we  take  $\sup$ over  all  possible  unit  length vector  fields $X$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Now  I revise my question. Could I clarify my question?

Comment: Your question is better now, but why not just say that the sup is to be taken over all $1$-forms $\alpha$ of $g$-length $1$?  Thinking of the vector field $X$ doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Thank you. I revise it again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no reason to believe that there is a supremum of this functional.  For example, consider the $3$-torus $M = \mathbb{R}^3/\mathbb{Z}^3$
with the quotient metric and the unit $1$-forms
$$
\alpha_n = \cos(2\pi n z)\,\mathrm{d} x - \sin(2\pi n z)\,\mathrm{d} y,
$$
where $n$ is an integer, which are well-defined on $M$.

One finds by calculation that
$$
\alpha_n\wedge\mathrm{d}\alpha_n = 2\pi n\, \mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y\wedge\mathrm{d}z\,
$$
Hence 
$$
\int_M \alpha_n\wedge\mathrm{d}\alpha_n = 2\pi n,
$$
so that the integral you describe can be made arbitrarily large (positive or negative) by appropriate choice of $\alpha$.

I expect that some similar construction could be made for any compact oriented $3$-manifold, showing that the functional is always unbounded (in either direction).

Comment: I honestly  have  admiration to your magnanimous  and  noble because  while there are a lot  of deeper question in MO  but  you  have  open and  kind conduct  to  beginner or people  as  me whose questions  are not deep. I observed this  during  my  activity in MO. My  best regard to you.